# Is 0.24681012141618202224... transcendental?

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendental-number-theory

Is a number whose infinite decimal part is the sequence of even numbers, transcendental? How about a number whose infinite decimal part is the odd numbers? Would the odds be more difficult to prove since they contain almost the entire sequence of primes?

Comment: Both are transcendental, and neither is really harder to establish than the other.

Comment: An excellent reference for results on transcendental number theory is [MR2077395 (2005f:11145)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2077395) Reviewed. 
Burger, Edward B.(1-WLMS); Tubbs, Robert(1-CO), **[Making transcendence transparent. 
An intuitive approach to classical transcendental number theory](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4757-4114-8)**. Springer-Verlag, New York, 2004. x+263 pp. ISBN: 0-387-21444-5.

Comment: The methods required to deal with the numbers you ask about are explained in sections 1.6 and 1.7 of that book. The result follows from the highly nontrivial [Roth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roth%27s_theorem), for which there are several very good (but somewhat sophisticated) references (the book does not include a complete proof of this result).

Comment: For a proof of Roth's theorem, I suggest for instance Chapter 6 of [MR2216774 (2007a:11092)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2216774) Reviewed. Bombieri, Enrico(1-IASP); Gubler, Walter(D-DORT), **[Heights in Diophantine geometry](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/heights-in-diophantine-geometry/4117673141D14050628601C428E8748D)**. New Mathematical Monographs, 4. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2006. xvi+652 pp. ISBN: 978-0-521-84615-8; 0-521-84615-3.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Is it easy to write down what the relevant rational approximations are? I don't see how to do it immediately.

Comment: @dhy, if you shift it left 2 places and subtract (that is to say, if you multiply by 99), the 101214161820...949698 part becomes 020202...0202. Shift left 3 places and see what happens to 100102104...994996998.

Comment: Thank you for the references! This is very nice to know!

Comment: I'm sorry but there was another tag - I think it was transcendental number theory that someone added. I removed it at first, but if you want to add it again that is great. Thanks!

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant, which is quite similar in nature.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In point of fact, K. Mahler proved in [this paper](https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/mahler/docs/046.pdf) that, if $p(x)$ in a non-constant polynomial such that $p(n) \in \mathbb{N}$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then the number

$$0.p(1)p(2)p(3)p(4)\ldots,$$

which is formed concatenating after the decimal point the values of $p(1), p(2), p(3), \ldots$ (in that order), is a transcendental and [non-Liouville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number) number.

Comment: Non-Liouville! That's wonderful!! I'm glad to know these are transcendental.

Comment: Are these numbers normal?

Comment: It is so interesting that you can make transcendental numbers from polynomials :)

Comment: I want to tell my students that the sequences of both odd and even numbers are transcendental! How many numbers are transcendental this way? It must be countable?

Comment: There are only countably many polynomials which take natural values at all naturals (since any polynomial is entirely determined by its values on the naturals), so yes, countable.

Comment: Thank you Patrick Stevens. There are so many more transcendentals! Even without all the numbers you make from algebraic numbers or polynomials, the same, countable.

Comment: @ErinCarmody: The proof the normality of these numbers was the subject matter of a 1952 paper of H. Davenport & P. Erdös: https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1952-04.pdf

Comment: What do you mean by non-constant? 0.42424242... is not transcendental but the polynomial is not constant.

Comment: In this case, the underlying polynomial may be taken as p(x) = 42...

Comment: @MateenUlhaq: What polynomial? There is no polynomial whose values at natural numbers are 4,2,4,2,...